# I'm a little confused about install OpenNTF Domino API

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs, xpages-extlib

I need to use [FileSilo Project](http://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/FileSilo) that require [OpenNTF Domino API](http://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/OpenNTF%20Domino%20API/releases/E497DF1D493B0ACC86257D5F007B3AD2).
But I have some problem to install this fantastic tool.
I have follow the suggest [of this blogger](https://frostillic.us/blog/posts/18E54DA31E8C3D6085257D5F0061660B)

So I have follow this step:

1. Download the last version of  OpenNTF Domino API
2. Unzip the file
3. Import Database **updateserver.nsf** from the zip, into my UpdateSite (se the image)
   [image: import database]
4. Install in my Designer from my updatesite.nsf[image]
5. restart HTTP task

Now I have this problems:

1. In my Domino Console after I restart the HTTP I see some error[image: Console Domino]
2. In my Domino Designer I see many error [image]
3. When I open FileSilo  on the web I see another error[image: filesiloerror]

Soo am I doing wrong ?

**UPDATED**
After the @Paul Stephen Withers comment.. I've installed the correct library (updatedesigner.nsf) into my Domino Designer...now FileSilo app show only this two error:
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The message on the Domino console about not finding a logging configuration file is fine. It's not an error, just information being logged out to the default log location. That just allows you to use a separate logging config file, outside of the API itself.

It looks like the key issue is the Designer install. Looking at the version number, I think you've installed the plugin from the server Update Site database into Designer.

The separate update site for Designer - updateDesigner.nsf - was needed in order to get typeahead but ensure the plugin for the server was as small as possible.

Because of the different packaging methods, you will need to uninstall from Application management before installing the newer version from updateDesigner.nsf. Note that a problem with DateTime class was identified which is fixed in "OpenNTF Domino API RC2.1.zip".

It looks like the errors on the web may be because it's been built in Designer.

Comment: tnx you I have re - installed into my designer the updateDesigner.nsf and now the error are only two. I have updated my question

Comment: Please make sure to remove ALl proior versions of the API you may find in DDE before installing the RC2.1 from the local updatesite.

Comment: @Oliver: I have installed OpenNTF Domino API RC2.1..How can I check  if I have old version? This is the first time that I install this on my designer

Comment: File, Application, Application Management. Open the branchs that points to your data/workspace folder (where custom plugins are installed). There you may find several entries of "OpenNTF Domino API". Kick everything that is not version "1.5.0.201409261724" and let the client do the restart.

Comment: @Oliver: yes, I've the last version only. Now I see only two error. FileSilo Bug or OpenNTF bug? Se my updated question.

Comment: Any chance that there is an old JAR file deployed in your local /jvm/lib/ext folder of a prior version of the API? Had this, too as the older versions were not available as OSGi plugin but only as JAR file.

Comment: @Oliver: no..this is my first installation of OpenNTF API...Before Nothing API was installed..I've changed List<DateTime> to Vector<Object> ... and work all very well!

Comment: I did come across some problems with RC2 and DateTimes, which came out when I tested the demo database. It was promptly fixed by RC2.1, which is why it's important not to use the RC2 version.

Comment: @Paul Stephen Withers: Yes Paul, I use the RC2.1 version.This is my first installation of API..I have downloaded the latest version ;-)

Comment: On that updated error message - with the Date.  You MIGHT want to try using doc.getItemValue("myDateField", Date.class)  - something like that at least.  I don't fully get it but that should tell the API to return a date for sure.

Answer (score 3):

I recently did a video on installing various plugins for your server and designer.  Near the end I showed the install of the OpenNTF Domino API.  That might be helpful to you.

http://www.notesin9.com/2014/10/21/notesin9-161-designer-plugins/